# How to use help cmd in Vim to view .txt files?

Tags: linux, vim, editor, gzip, vi

I'm using Vim 7.4 on Fedora 20. I unzipped all the `.txt.gz` files in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc` and when I try to use the `help` command in Vim's command line it gives an error saying `E429: File "/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/starting.txt.gz" does not exist`. I did that because when I was using the `help` cmd before unzipping the files, it showed me some encrypted binary text. So, I thought that uzipping the filed might resolve the problem but, obviously, it didn't. Now, I don't know what to do? Can I configure the file extensions that `help` searches for in the `/doc` folder or something like that? What to do?

And yeah, I don't want to compress the files again. A way to resolve this problem without having to re-compress the files, is what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm talking about using **:help** in the Vim command line @Skynet . Not in the gnome terminal.

Comment: I suspect that the encrypted binary file was actually `starting.txt.gz` but not extracted. Do you have gzip installed? Edit: obviously you do, since you said you extracted them. It looks like Vim is suppose to extract the help files before displaying them, but it isn't. Not sure why, but maybe that info can help you Google.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought and the reason why I unzipped the files. I tried searching for it. Like, how to enable gzip in Vim and all that but no luck.

Comment: Did you install it from the official Fedora repository? If so, I would reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, delete the old tags file:

```
rm /usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/tags
```

Then, run vim as root to regenerate help tags file:

```
sudo vim -c 'helptags /usr/share/vim/vim74/doc' +qall
```

Finally, [fix vim's ability to read gz files](https://superuser.com/questions/508425/vim-is-not-reading-gzipped-files-automatically) for future convenience.

Comment: @RavishAhmadKhan This post does not suggest or recommend compressing the files again.